# Format string with spaces

Tags: c++, string

I'm trying to make an elegant logging system in C++. I'm currently using `printf()`, although `cout` can also be an option.

What I want to achieve is something like this

```
console_log( "ClassName", "funcName", "Message." );
```

My current code for this is simply:

```
static void console_log( const std::string & className, const std::string & funcName, const std::string & message ) {
    printf( "%s : %s : %s\n",  className.c_str(), funcName.c_str(), message.c_str() );
}
```

It prints nicely, like this

```
// For example:
console_log( "MenuPanel", "selectedThisButton", "Something happened." );
console_log( "MenuPanel", "selectedAnotherButton", "Another thing happened." );

// Output:
MenuPanel : selectedThisButton : Something happened.
MenuPanel : selectedAnotherButton : Another thing happened.
```

However, I want it to be printed in a table-like manner, where all "columns" are aligned properly. For example:

```
MenuPanel : selectedThisButton    : Something happened.
MenuPanel : selectedAnotherButton : Another thing happened.
```

How do I make it so that the first and second "columns" have the exact same width/number of characters, with additional spaces if necessary? It doesn't need to be dynamic. Something like setting a "column" to 16 characters will do.

I don't wish to use any third-party libs for something as simple as this, though. And if possible, no `boost`.

Comment: An "elegant logging system in C++" must be the single most re-invented wheel ever.

Comment: How do you want to fix the width? If it is hardcoded, you can just add as many spaces as you need, after computing the length of the string.

Comment: Not even attempting this simple counting problem is evidence enough for me that the question should be closed. Oh, and, [`printf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) has alignment operators if one should read the man page (e.g. `printf( "%-16s", ... );`).

Comment: printf( "%s : %s : %s\n",  className.c_str(), funcName.c_str(), message.c_str() );    should be for example: printf( "%30s : %30s : %30s\n",  className.c_str(), funcName.c_str(), message.c_str() ); with whatever width you like as well you can check printf documentation for alignment modifiers

Comment: @ChronoTrigger I was hoping for a simple one-liner to format the string instead of creating a function with 10+ lines.

Comment: @evilruff Let me read about that and see what I can do.

Comment: PP and evilruff It seems to do the job. Can you post those as answers so I can accept them? Thanks. :)

Comment: @LanceGray If you're doing any string processing at all, you'll have most of the functions you need to make it a one-liner already available.  Do you output text anywhere elsewhere in your code---you should have an `alignedText` manipulator for the iostream.  Do you format text anywhere: you should have an `rightPad` function in your toolbox, because you'll use it everywhere.

Comment: Reconsider using boost, specifically the stream stuff of boost::format.  You will definitely thank yourself if you can manage the dependency.  It might even save your sanity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you up to go in 'keep it simple' way you can replace:

```
printf( "%s : %s : %s\n", className.c_str(), funcName.c_str(), 
message.c_str() );
```

to

```
printf( "%30s : %30s : %30s\n", className.c_str(), funcName.c_str(), 
message.c_str() );
```

with whatever width you like as well you can check printf documentation for alignment modifiers.

Comment: Of course, this doesn't actually format like he wants.  The embedded language used by `printf` isn't _that_ simple.

Comment: well, I started to program C language much earlier then cout appears =) and printf is not that hard.. compare for example things like:   printf( "(%0.10X) %0.10X %s\n", threadId, objectId, message ).. with an amount of code you need for cout

Answer (score 4):

I'd use I/O streams instead of C-style `printf` and for printing stuff (of any kind) with specific width you can then include `<iomanip>` and set [field width](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/setw/):

```
some_stream << std::setw(MY_WIDTH) << whatever;
```

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::setw(10) << "hi";
}
```

outputs:

```
        hi
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you prefer I/O streams over `printf()`?

Comment: @LanceGray: It's always better to prefer what the standard library offers over the old C-style solutions that some might find "ghastly" :)

Comment: +1 as the question is tagged `C++`, not because `<iostream>` must be better because it's in the standard library.

Comment: @LihO Honestly I think that printf() functionality gives you much elegant/readable code then cout formatting which more looks like a 'patch' to keep stream formatting within standard c++ library..

Comment: @LihO Okay, thanks. I'll keep that in mind. I just got used to `printf()` because that is what I was taught ever since I started programming.

Comment: I didn't write that using I/O streams must be better. I just wrote that I would stick with I/O streams. Another reason might be that I'd follow RAII and thus probably sending the data all over my application in form of objects such as `std::string`, so I'd incline to something like `stream << string` more intuitively.

Comment: @LanceGray Maybe the fact that they actually work, without all of the risks of undefined behavior, and without having to learn a separate meta-language.

Comment: @evilruff Code using `printf` is certainly not more maintainable.  `printf` requires putting literal information about the formatting directly in the format string, which is a maintenance nightmare, and requires matching the format string with the types being used, which is a second maintenance nightmare.

Comment: Just not to copy-paste things, there is a discussion about that in the comments to accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359989/string-formatting-c/18361091?noredirect=1#comment26958618_18361091...

Comment: I think that formatting how its implemented in std lib 1) inconvenient to use 2) breaks whole idea of stream when you actually SEND something into STREAM which affects it's behaviour for the rest of the world.. and for data you sending after that.. I am not against, just I am not using them, because with format modifiers in printf you can write in one line things for which you sometimes a page of code in cout..

Comment: @evilruff In this case, the accepted answer isn't the best nor the idiomatic solution.  Anyone who has used C++ for a bit has a toolbox with all of the necessary tools; in particular, with the necessary manipulators.

Comment: @evilruff The idea of keeping the formatting state in the stream is irksome, and seems to lack elegance.  To date, however, no one seems to have come up with a better idea.

Comment: that's why I prefer to use printf rather then using something I don't like =) Why should I bother... anyway in most of cases in the area I work its mostly about logging.. also if you measure with any decent profiler an overhead you are getting with cout then logging something in high loading system you will be surprised in the difference between printfs and/or fprintf to file handle vs cout things...

Answer (score 0):

The general solution is quite complicated, but if you can assume
a fixed width font (where every character has the same width),
and know the width of each column up front, something like:

```
std::string rPad( std::string const& original, int minWidth )
{
    return original
        + std::string( 
            std::max( minWidth - static_cast<int>( original.size() ), 0 ),
            ' ' );
}

void console_log(
    std::string const& className,
    std::string const& funcName,
    std::string const& message )
{
    std::cout << rPad( className, classNameWidth )
        << " : " << rPad( funcName, funcNameWidth )
        << " : " << rPad
        << std::endl;
}
```

Alternatively, you can do something like:

```
void console_log(
    std::string const& className,
    std::string const& funcName,
    std::string const& message )
{
    std::cout << alignedText( classNameWidth ) << className
        << " : " << alignedText( funcNameWidth ) << funcName
        << " : " << message << std::endl;
}
```

The manipulator `alignedText` is generally useful, and you
should have it in your toolbox anyway:

```
class alignedText
{
    mutable std::ostream* myOwner;
    mutable std::ostream::fmtflags myFlags;
    int myWidth;
public:
    alignedText( int width ) : myOwner myWidth( width ) {}
    ~alignedText()
    {
        if ( myOwner != nullptr ) {
            myOwner->flags( myFlags );
        }
    }
    void set( std::ostream& dest ) const
    {
        if ( myOwner == nullptr ) {
            myOwner = &dest;
            myFlags = myOwner->flags();
        }
        dest.setf( std::ios_base::left, std::ios_base::adjustfield );
        dest.width( myWidth );
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& dest, alignedText const& manip )
    {
        manip.set( dest );
        return dest;
    }
};
```

(While the same thing can be done using `printf`, the results
are a lot less readable, totally unmaintainable, and of course,
you have the general fragility of `printf`.)